# App crashes when using UIImagePickerController to access album

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

iTunes Connect has a crash report for my app. It says that the app will crash when I use `UIImagePickerController` to access an album, but I can't reproduce the issue either in the simulator or on a real machine. The following is the contents of the crash report. Please help me pinpoint the problem.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         eyerecolor [5011]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B9D7CEA3-DB1D-4CE3-B605-90EC066B7C92/eyerecolor.app/eyerecolor
Identifier:      eyerecolor
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]


Date/Time:       2012-04-06 18:51:37.692 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x371198bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163

1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x324891e5 objc_exception_throw + 33

2   CoreData                       0x3728c64b -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator setMetadata:forPersistentStore:] + 411

3   PhotoLibraryServices           0x31585ffd +[PLManagedObjectContext(Private) recordVersion:forStore:] + 393

4   PhotoLibraryServices           0x31586385 +[PLManagedObjectContext(Private) configurePersistentStoreCoordinator:] + 897

5   PhotoLibraryServices           0x3158691f __69+[PLManagedObjectContext(Protected) sharedPersistentStoreCoordinator]_block_invoke_0323 + 179

6   libdispatch.dylib              0x32a908cf _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 27

7   libdispatch.dylib              0x32a9072f dispatch_barrier_sync_f$VARIANT$mp + 63

8   libdispatch.dylib              0x32a9034f dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$mp + 19

9   libdispatch.dylib              0x32a909f9 dispatch_sync$VARIANT$mp + 33

10  PhotoLibraryServices           0x3158681f +[PLManagedObjectContext(Protected) sharedPersistentStoreCoordinator] + 155

11  PhotoLibraryServices           0x315853c9 -[PLManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:useSharedPersistentStoreCoordinator:] + 121

12  PhotoLibraryServices           0x315852a7 +[PLManagedObjectContext contextForPhotoLibrary:] + 115

13  PhotoLibraryServices           0x31584ec9 -[PLPhotoLibrary(Protected) loadDatabase] + 237

14  PhotoLibraryServices           0x3154d87d -[PLPhotoLibrary initWithPath:canTriggerDatabaseUpdate:] + 305

15  PhotoLibraryServices           0x315942a1 __42+[PLSharedPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]_block_invoke_0 + 61

16  libdispatch.dylib              0x32a92683 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 47

17  PhotoLibraryServices           0x3159425f +[PLSharedPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] + 83

18  PhotoLibrary                   0x32c69bc9 -[PLUILibraryViewController _updateFilteredAlbumListWithFilter:] + 157

19  PhotoLibrary                   0x32c6961b -[PLUILibraryViewController init] + 67

20  UIKit                          0x31f58cc5 -[UIImagePickerController _createInitialController] + 317

21  UIKit                          0x31f58d05 -[UIImagePickerController _setupControllersForCurrentSourceType] + 25

22  UIKit                          0x31f58711 -[UIImagePickerController viewWillAppear:] + 69

23  UIKit                          0x31d336b5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 145

24  UIKit                          0x31d8e61b -[UIViewController beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 191

25  UIKit                          0x31dd4691 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 4077

26  UIKit                          0x31dd314f -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3123

27  UIKit                          0x044f2e93 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 51

28  UIKit                          0x31e2dd97 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 31

29  eyerecolor                     0x00009c39 -[eyerecolorViewController showImagePicker:] (eyerecolorViewController.m:1855)
```

---

```
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType]) {
        self.m_pickerView.sourceType = sourceType;
        self.m_pickerView.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:self.m_pickerView animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (self.m_pickerView == nil) {
        self.m_pickerView = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.m_pickerView.delegate = self;
        self.m_pickerView.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you use to call UIImagePicker Controller?

Comment: OK,Here is the code
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
    {
  self.m_pickerView.sourceType = sourceType;
        self.m_pickerView.allowsEditing = NO;
  [self presentModalViewController:self.m_pickerView animated:YES];
 
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 if (self.m_pickerView == nil) {
  self.m_pickerView = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
  self.m_pickerView.delegate = self;
        self.m_pickerView.allowsImageEditing = NO;
 }
}

Comment: Put the code into your question, so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your issue, but hopefully it will help...

Have you tried your code on iOS 5? And what about your device?

Looking at the crash report your issue seems to be related to iOS 5 on iPhone 4S:

```
Hardware Model: iPhone4,1
...
OS Version: iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
```

Try to NOT autorelease your `UIImagePickerController`. Sometimes autoreleased objects create problems instead of smoothing memory management.

EDIT: One more thing... Here the way Apple suggests to implement UIImagePickerController:

1. Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the
   desired source. Do this calling the isSourceTypeAvailable: class
   method, providing a constant from the
   “UIImagePickerControllerSourceType” enum.
2. Check which media types are available, for the source type you’re
   using, by calling the availableMediaTypesForSourceType: class
   method. This lets you distinguish between a camera that can be used
   for video recording and one that can be used only for still images.
3. Tell the image picker controller to adjust the UI according to the
   media types you want to make available—still images, movies, or
   both—by setting the mediaTypes property.
4. Present the user interface by calling the
   **presentViewController:animated:completion:** method of the currently
   active view controller, passing your configured image picker
   controller as the new view controller. On iPad, present the user
   interface using a popover. Doing so is valid only if the sourceType
   property of the image picker controller is set to
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. To use a popover
   controller, use the methods described in “Presenting and Dismissing
   the Popover” in UIPopoverController Class Reference.
5. When the user taps a button to pick a newly-captured or saved image
   or movie, or cancels the operation, dismiss the image picker using
   your delegate object. For newly-captured media, your delegate can
   then save it to the Camera Roll on the device. For previously-saved
   media, your delegate can then use the image data according to the
   purpose of your app.

From [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

EDIT (again): Well, it is very odd if you do not have any issue on your devices, but again I try to suggest a way to change actual situation.

Implement your UIImagePicker Controller in showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType instead of viewDidLoad.

Use allowsEditing instead of allowsImageEditing (deprecated in iOS 3.1) and do not autorelease your object...

Comment: 1.I have tried it on my iPhone 4s on iOS 5, but I can't reproduce the issue.I also tried it on my iPad 2 and iPod touch 4, still runs well.I don't know the env of the problem user.
2.presentViewController is only available on iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

okay heres a couple of things that came to my mind. I hope its gonna work....

First of all Check whether u included UIImagePickerDelegate in ur Controller's .h file. Secondly there are delegate methods like didFinshPickingImage try to search that on the Class Reference Beppe gave you.

If these thing didnt work tell me whether ur app gives a Sigbrt or Bad Excess ... From My experience i believe it will be a sigbrt.
and if i m not wrong ur app will be taking u to main.m file. Ofcourse u wont be able to tell whats wrongs so add A EXCEPTION BREAK POINT in ur App. which will give u the exact point after which ur app crashes.

search that point. what i really thing is ur delegate methods are not working.

and if its a worst case and u still dont find solution the last resorts is [THIS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/photo-picker)

LEt ME Know if it worked :)
Cheers

Comment: 1.Controller's .h file already included UIImagePickerDelegate.

Comment: 1.Controller's .h file already included UIImagePickerDelegate.
2.It's SIGABRT, yes app will be taking to main.m file.

Now the main problem is that I can't reproduce the bug, I have tried it on all of my devices and all version( iOS 3,4,5), my codes still run well.

Comment: okay did u tried the Exception break point.... it will tell u where the bug it.... tell me 2ndly did u tried the link i gave u....